# Is it possible to concatenate onto PHP $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have an application that is using session variables. I am trying to pass the path of an image to another PHP page, but since the page is in another location my path breaks and the images won't display. Is there a way to concatenate onto the path in the `$_SESSION` variable?

`page1.php`

```
<?php 
session_name('Private');
session_start();
$_SESSION['first_img'] = '<img src="img/first-img.png">';
$_SESSION['second_img'] = '<img src="img/second-img.png">';
?>
```

`page2.php`

```
<?php 
session_name('Private');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['first_img'];
echo $_SESSION['first_img'];
?>
```

since `page2.php` is in another folder, I would need to add `../` to the beginning of the `src` in the image path. I can't figure out how to add it to the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: First of all you need to use session_start(); in the BEGIN of your session BEFORE you name your session... Try to change that in both files and take a look if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible solution might consider storing the relative path in the session variable, and then wrapping the differences in your echo code.

`page1.php`

```
<?php 
session_name('Private');
session_start();
$_SESSION['first_img'] = 'img/first-img.png';
$_SESSION['second_img'] = 'img/second-img.png';
?>
```

`page2.php`

```
<?php 
session_name('Private');
session_start();
echo '<img src="../' . $_SESSION['first_img'] . '">';
echo '<img src="../' . $_SESSION['first_img'] . '">';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this is the answer I decided to use. Its so simple and obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths.

```
$_SESSION['first_img'] = '<img src="//'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/img/first-img.png">';
$_SESSION['second_img'] = '<img src="//'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/img/second-img.png">';
```

Comment: You're missing a `/`. Should be `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/img ...`